# Sync Framework Error (Range was provided out of expected order.)

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

Hi We are using Sync framework for syncing between SQL CE and SQL Server on server side.

For some newly entered data in the server side, sync throws an error

Range was provided out of expected order. Ranges should be provided in increasing order.

Any pointers on how to resolve this error

Comment: Can you please provide the error message and stacktrace? Also, does this solution make sense in your case: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/syncgeneral/thread/d559af57-ae38-4897-8bc7-def4f25bc539 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. The Sync Framework expects the Current version values to be provided to it in an increasing order. The stored procedure in our application was returning the objects ordered by GUID and not current version.

A one line fix in the stored procedure fixed this errro